# g[lobal] with a s[ubstitution]

Tags: gvim, global-command

I would like to add a dot after the first number in a line. I tried using the command below.

```
:g/\v^\d/exe "norm!:s/\v(\d)/\1\./^M"
```

The command above does not work. I recorded the macro `@q=':s/\v\€kb(\d)/\1./^M'` that substitutes like below.

```
:g/\v^\d/exe "norm!@q"
```

Why does the first way does not work? How should it be done without the macro?

Comment: I've included the details in my answer below, but the tl;dr version is that you need to escape the backslashes within the `"..."`

Answer (score 2):

The `:global` command takes a series of Ex commands to execute on the marked lines. `:substitute` is one-such, so use it directly:

```
:global/^\d/substitute/\v(\d)/\1.
```

Though as noted this (in this particular case) equivalent to

```
:%substitute/^\d/&.
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, let me walk you through a set of steps to refine the command, starting with a slightly revised version of your try (modified only enough to make it work):

```
:g/^\d/exe "norm! :s/\\v(\\d)/\\1./\<CR>"
```

An alternative to using the `very magic` and atoms/match groups:

```
:g/^\d/exe "norm! :s/\\d/&./\<CR>"
```

Dropping redundant `norm`:

```
:g/^\d/exe "s/\\d/&./"
```

Dropping the `exe`:

```
:g/^\d/s/\d/&./
```

Combining `g[lobal]` and `s[ubstitute]` has its uses, but for the example you provided `g` isn't actually needed:

```
:%s/^\d/&./
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!